# How to reference property in ViewModel from Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view model class that has an attribute called Title that I would like to render on the Index view in Razor

CLASS

```
public class vmAppointment
{
    public Appointment Appointment { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EmployeeList { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

INDEX VIEW

```
@model IEnumerable<JJ.ViewModels.vmAppointment>

<h2>@Model.Title</h2>  WRONG!  how can i reference my property here?
```

how can I render the property value in the view?

Answer (score 4):

Your view is strongly typed to a collection of `vmAppointment`, not a single `vmAppointment`. So in order to reference the `Title` you're gonna have to loop through the elements of this collection. For example:

```
@foreach (var appointment in Model)
{
    <div>Appointment title: @appointment.Title</div>
}
```

Alternatively if you want your view to be strongly typed to a single `vmAppointment` instead of a collection have your controller action return a single instance of this class:

```
vmAppointment model = ...
return View(model);
```

and then make your view strongly typed to a single appointment and you will be able to directly reference the `Title` property:

```
@model JJ.ViewModels.vmAppointment
<h2>@Html.DisplyFor(x => x.Title)</h2>
```